# facebook application doesn't print user location and user likes

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After the login the app should print my hometown and my likes of Facebook but it prints anything, how can i make it? the code only prints my ID, my fullname, my photo and the birthday. i try to find some solutions but it doesn't work.

```
        // graph api request for user data
        $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=email,name,hometown,location,friends,age_range,birthday');
        $response = $request->execute();

        // get response
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); 
        $fbuser_location = $graphObject->getProperty('user_hometown');    
        $fbpublic_profile = $graphObject->getProperty('public_profile');
        $fbuser_about_me = $graphObject->getProperty('user_about_me');
        $fbbirthday = $graphObject->getProperty('birthday');
        $fbmail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');
        $fbuser_likes = $graphObject->getProperty('user_likes');


        // ********** PRINT GRAPH *********************
        $graphArray = $response->getGraphObject()->AsArray();
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphArray, 1 ) . '</pre>';
        // ********************************************

        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['HOMETOWN'] =  $fbhometown;
        $_SESSION['AGE_RANGE'] =  $fbage_range;
        $_SESSION['USER_ABOUT_ME'] =  $fbuser_about_me;
        $_SESSION['BIRTHDAY'] =  $fbbirthday;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $fbemail;
        $_SESSION['USER_LIKES'] =  $fbuser_likes;

        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email, public_profile, user_friends,user_location,user_friends,user_about_me'));
        header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
    }

} catch( Exception $ex ) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

?> 


here i copy the mainpag

                <ul class="nav nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-header">Image</li>
                    <li><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['FBID']; ?>/picture"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Facebook ID</li>
                    <li><?php echo  $_SESSION['FBID']; ?></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Facebook fullname</li>
                    <li><?php echo $_SESSION['FULLNAME']; ?></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Facebook Email</li>
                    <li><?php echo $_SESSION['EMAIL']; ?></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Facebook Birthday</li>
                    <li><?php echo $_SESSION['BIRTHDAY']; ?></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Facebook Location</li>
                    <li><?php echo $_SESSION['USER_HOMETOWN']; ?></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">User Likes</li>
                    <li><?php echo $_SESSION['USER_LIKES']; ?></li>


                    <div>
                        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>     <!-- Before login -->
```

Comment: What version of the app are you using? To retrieve hometown you need to request and accept user_hometown. In your scope you are asking for user_friends twice. Only friends that use your app will be returned. Did you accept all the permissions requested? Have the permissions been reviewed and approved by Facebook? Is your App in Production? Does the user logged into your App have a role in the App - ie admin, developer, etc?